# Why is Git making a fake diff with the word "total" with a decimal at the top?

Tags: git

I have a problem. In Git, whenever I do "git status -v", there is one particular file which will have the following diff:

```
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-   total     5895.99
+   total     5896.93
```

Except every time I get the diff, the bottom number changes. For example, now it's:

```
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-   total     5895.99
+   total     5897.35
```

Note that 5896.93 is different than 5897.35.

This diff is at the first line in the file.

However if I open the file that is associated with this diff, the word "total" does not appear anywhere in the file, nor does the number shown. In fact, the particular line shown in the diff does not appear at all anywhere in the entire project.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this phantom, mutating diff to keep showing up?

Note: we are using a git filter on that particular file which performs a clean/smudge operation on the file, but I use the exact same filter on other files in the project without this weird problem happening.

The git version is "git version 2.7.4 (Apple Git-66)".

Comment: Please post the filter, so we can understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the unix command "ac". I had slipped a typo into my script where there was an extraneous "ac" at the end of a line inside a case statement.

The unix command "ac" outputs:

```
total     5898.57
```

From "man ac":

> A record of individual login and logout times are written to the
>   system log by login(8) and  launchd(8), respectively.  The program ac
>   examines these records and writes the accumulated connect time (in
>   decimal hours) for all logins to the standard output.

Hence why the number was changing every time I would do a git diff.

Well, I've had weirder days, but not many.